# How to control text in edittext with textwatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

So I'm trying to make user insert text with some format that should be xx.xxxx. For that I'm using textwatcher class. Here is my class:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
            if(edittext.getText().length()==2)edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString()+".");

        }
    });
```

So i basicly just add '.' if length after editing is 2. But after i do that it set my cursor to start of the text field and when i try to delete dot it just recreate it because length is again 2. I know there is some solution but it seems i can't figure it out today :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use `EditText.append` instead of `EditText.setText` and move cursor at edittext as :

```
  Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if(edittext.getText().length()==2){

            // append dot to edittext
            edittext.append(".");
            // move cursor at end position in EditText
            edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
          }
    }
```

Comment: When I do that, in 4.0v or superior, the cursor stay before the "." , and In 2.2v works fine, but in both I can't delete the characters